# Android studio how to build a project from github source

Tags: android, github, android-studio

How do I build a android studio project from github repository that only contains the source codes, no gradle build information. For example. I want to build a project from this repository https://github.com/googledrive/android-quickstart, but the android project could not be built correctly. Can I just add the build.gradle and expect the project to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a project in eclipse.  Just download the zip file, and extract it.  Then in android studio, import the existing Eclipse project by hitting File -> Import Project.  Android Studio will just build you a AS project, including all the gradle files.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers!

Answer (score 1):

You can just create a new project with same package name as in the github project.

This will create a compilable android project/library. after that manually copy the code by downloading from github (download as zip) and then just copy the source folder.

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways to do this that I know of officially.

> 1) Add project directly

*Step 1:*

Add project into following directory `{App Root Folder}/Libraries/` (create libraries folder if doesn't exist)

*Step 2:*

Go to `File/Project Structure/` under Dependencies tab click green add icon and select Module dependency and select the project you added to libraries.

> 2) Add project as a `.jar/.aar`

*Step 1:*

Either look for a the version of `.jar/.aar` you are looking for on web or compile project to `.jar/.aar.`

*Step 2:*

Follow Step one for previous way but instead select `Library dependency`

> 3) Add project from Maven

Step 1:

Find library on [gradleplease.appspot.com](http://gradleplease.appspot.com)

*Step 2:*

Add `compile 'package name'` under dependencies in your apps `build.gradle`